# Toggle button both by click and by function

Tags: javascript, function, button, toggle

I got a problem switching a button both ways, by clicking on it and by changing it by a js-function which reacts on recieved mqtt messages and toggles the button. The first part works, the latter not. Here is my html

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="onoff_dev();">
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

The js to toggle the button:

```
function onoff_dev() {
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
    if (currentvalue == "Off") {
        document.getElementById("onoff").value = "On";
        switch("0");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("onoff").value = "Off";
        switch("1");
    }
}
```

And here the function, which is executed when a mqtt message arrives. The message is either     'r_message = On' or 'r_message = Off' It should change the slide button, but "document.getElementById('onoff').value  = "On";" does not update the value of the button.

```
function onMessageArrived(r_message) {
    if (r_message == "On") {
        document.getElementById('onoff').value  = "On";
    }
    if (r_message == "Off") {
        document.getElementById('onoff').value  = "Off";
    }
}
```

Can you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why you are comparing "r_message" in the first "if" of the "onMessageArrived" function and "r_message.payloadString" in the second "if"? Wasn't it supposed to be in the two "if" the same property?

Comment: oh, sorry, I tried to simplify the code before posting and oversaw the r_message.payloadString. Now it is correct.

Comment: what is the function `switch("0")`?

Comment: if you are trying to check or uncheck the input with javascript depending on r_message value use `document.getElementById('onoff').checked = true` instead of  `document.getElementById('onoff').value  = "On";` replace true with false when r_message is "Off"

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! that helped. I did not know that there is a difference between .checked and .value. Can you recomend an overview on that subject?